# OLS coefficients change signs at some point in time

Tags: regression, time-series, finance

I am running an OLS in which the dependent variable is the sum of daily log returns on S&P 500 and as independent variables I use some variables which I believe "drive" the SPX returns.

My data span from 2001 to 2017 and at some point during the financial crisis (2007) appears that two of them (credit spread and default spread) change signs.

What could be the reason(s) for that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of reason are you looking for? Explanation of statistics, how sign changes can occur and what they mean. Or, explanation of economy, how these factors can show this behavior in the statistics?

Comment: I am looking more for an economic explanation. What could be the reason after the financial crisis (2007-2009) the same variables affect in opposite direction the returns. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your variables are, but undoubtedly the economic explanation you seek is in your sentence.  The 2007 credit crisis resulted in a huge change in the relationship between different credit entities.  The fear of default from anything except a government entity spiked.  I'm pretty sure that this is not the correct forum for your question to be answered, but if it is you will need to provide more information as to exactly what your variables were measuring.

Comment: Check out Didier Sornette's papers on thermal optimal path analysis ... https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2529961

Comment: Thank you aginensky. Credit spread measures the difference between Moody's Baa and Aaa corporate bond yields. Default spread is the TED spread.

Comment: Aginensky, do you think it better suit to economics exchange?